# Regex to find a word that includes an escaped character

Tags: c#, vb.net, regex

I am using a simple regular expression (in C#) to find a whole word within a block of text.

The word may appear at the beginning, end or in the middle of a the text or sentence with in the text.

The expression I have been using `\bword\b` has been working fine however if the word included a special character (that has been escaped) it no longer works. The boundary is essential so that we do not pick up words such as vb.net as a match for .net.

Two examples that fail are:

```
\bc\#\b

\b\.net\b
```

I can change the word boundary to a list of other checks such as not at the start non-space etc. however this is complex and can be slow if used on a large number of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\b` matches the boundary between word characters and non-word characters, but won't match the boundary between two non-word characters.

For example, in the case of `C#` there's a boundary between the `C` (a word character) and the `#` (a non-word character) but not between the `#` and whatever comes after it (space, punctuation, end-of-string etc).

You can workaround this problem as follows:

- Use `(?:^|\W)` instead of `\b` at the beginning of the expression.
  For example, `(?:^|\W)\.NET\b`
  This will match either the start-of-string or a non-word character before the `.` character.
- Use `(?:\W|$)` instead of `\b` at the end of the expression.
  For example, `\bC#(?:\W|$)`
  This will match either a non-word character or the end-of-string after the `#` character.

Comment: This worked however as it was considerably slower on a few thousand calls I only run this if something needs to be escaped which is rare. Thanks

Comment: @John: You only need to use these workarounds if the non-word character is at the start or end of your seach term. If the term contains only word characters, or if the non-word characters are buried somewhere in the middle of the term (for example, `f@t`) then using `\b` will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!\w)c#(?!\w)

(?<!\w)\.net(?!\w)
```

That should be quicker than matching anchors or non-word characters, like `(?:^|\W)`, plus you don't have to deal with the extraneous characters when it's the `\W` that matches.

Comment: Good answer, better than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a match because the escaped characters (# and .) are not word characters, so there isn't a word-boundary (\b) between this and the whitespace/etc. Perhaps look for whitespace/bol/eol/etc specifically?

Comment: I have tried this and it does work but is considerably slower when running this for a few hundred words against a few hundred paragraphs of text